# Stripe List a Customer's PaymentMethods by multiple types

Tags: stripe-payments

How can we retrieve the list of payment methods attached to a customer with type= us_bank_account and card at one request? The type parameter can only support up to one value at a time.

https://stripe.com/docs/api/payment_methods/customer_list

```
curl -G https://api.stripe.com/v1/customers/cus_MT5jjlXfiQl4dH/payment_methods \
-u {Key} \
-d type=card
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is Stripe's answer:

> Hello there,
>
> Thank you for your patience. Claire sent me your case regarding
> payment_method listing, I'll do my best to help :
>
> Currently, listing both card and us_bank_account payment_methods would
> require two calls, each with a different type filter.
>
> The only feature that would circumvent this at this time would be
> Stripe Sigma, by querying the Payment_methods table :
> https://stripe.com/docs/stripe-data/write-queries
>
> I'll discuss your inquiry with our engineers so that a solution may be
> implemented in this regard. I would suggest subscribing to our
> developer updates for new features like these :
> https://go.stripe.global/subscribe
>
> I hope this information helps. Let me know if I can be of further
> assistance. Best, Lucas